# Why does the calculated harmonic series depend on the order of summation?

Tags: python

I have written two ways of calculating the harmonic series - one with a `while` loop and one with a `for` loop. The methods calculate and add the terms in opposite orders:

**H(x) = 1/x + ... + 1/2 + 1**

```
acc1 = 0

i = x
while i > 0:
    acc1 += 1/i
    i -= 1

print(acc1)
```

**H(x) = 1 + 1/2 + ... + 1/x**

```
acc2 = 0

for k in range(x):
    acc2 += 1/(k+1)

print(acc2)
```

The two methods find the sum of the same numbers. It is just the order that is different. But for `x >= 26`, I get a very small difference between the outputs (approx. `4e-16` for `x = 26`). I understand that floating point addition often causes small inaccuracies in programming due to recurring decimals in base 2 - but for adding the same numbers, why are the two outputs different?

Comment: You just answered yourself. Because of floating point math, addition is NOT commutative using floats. The error is well within range of float approximation errors.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken